# Eclipse Search Results are Missing When there are Exactly 404 Matches?

Tags: eclipse, search

#### Specification

- Eclipse: SpringSource Tool Suite
- Version: 2.9.1.RELEASE
- Build Id: 201203221000

#### What I do:

1. Search -> File
2. Containing text: "subheading"
3. File name patterns: "*, !*jquery.js, !*min.js"
4. Scope: Workspace
5. Click 'Search'

#### What I expect to happen:

- The Search tab will show search results for "subheading".

#### What happens:

- The Search tab starts to find results and puts them on the tab.
- The number of matches stops at 404 since there are exactly that many instances of "subheading" in my workspace.
- The file/directory names of each result turns blank.

#### My Suggestion For Duplicating:

- Make a test workspace with exactly 404 instances of a word.
- Search for it.

#### My Theory:

The developers of Eclipse are messing with me. I hope this isn't true, but I don't see why else it would do this. Can anyone else duplicate this and/or explain it?

#### Update:

After much more use of Eclipse, this same result seems to randomly occur (file/directory names turning blank). It happens consistently when there are 404 results, but it also happens randomly with other amounts.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Consider submitting a bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: I added the specs for Eclipse.

Comment: Nice bug report. I wish my testers would give me such reports. Put a Print Screen at the end and you are my man :)

Comment: This is happening to me as well.

Answer (score 6):

For a workaround. I found that I could switch to a different perspective and it gave me my search results back.

Comment: I have the same issue with Neon, but only in some workspaces, and strange enough but this does work...

Comment: I'm just amazed that eclipse don't see this as an issue and do something about it. The same problem has crept into STM32CubeIDE which is just a rebranded eclipse.